# Passing Classes with same interface or base class to overloaded methods

Tags: c#

I have a base class with has x amount of properties, I then have derived classes with more properties. How do I process the common fields in a method and then send the object to another method which can process its additional properties?

Example:

```
public Interface IAnimal {
    int NoOfFeet;
}

class Animal: IAnimal {
    int NoOfFeet {get;set;}
}

class Elephant: Animal {
   bool hasTrunk {get;set;}
}

class Dog:Animal {
   string canBark {get;set;}
}

Method1(IAnimal a) {
    //process NoOfFeet     ...

    //process fields for derived type
    DoSomething(IAnimal a)
}    

DoSomething(Elephant e) {
     //process trunk
}

DoSomething(Dog d) {
     //process canbark
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a *short but complete* example instead of pseudo-code with large amounts of unnecessary whitespace...

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, so I fixed that whitespace :).

Comment: sorry! thought the whitespace would help!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how this compiled at all, since `class` in C# needs to be lowercase and you had `Class`. In addition, all of these properties are private and so are not inherited.

Comment: It didn't need to compile as I wrote it freehand as an example for this question!!!

Comment: @user4968786 Ah well that makes sense then.

Comment: @user4968786: "It didn't need to compile" - that's half the problem. If you write a short but complete example which *does* compile, or which only fails to compile at the point of the question, it's easier to help you.

Comment: "thought the whitespace would help" - one line between methods/classes? Absolutely. Two? Maybe, at a push. **Six**? Absolutely not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you basically want overload resolution at execution time. (I'm assuming you can't introduce a virtual method to do the right thing, and implement it in each class. That would be the cleanest way if it's reasonable for the implementations to know what you're doing with them, but that's not always the case.) The simplest way of achieving that is using `dynamic`, as introduced in C# 4:

```
public void Method(IAnimal animal)
{
    // We don't want to call Handle with a null reference,
    // or we'd get an exception to due overload ambiguity
    if (animal == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("animal");
    }
    // Do things with just the IAnimal properties
    Handle((dynamic) animal);
}

private void Handle(Dog dog)
{
    ...
}

private void Handle(Elephant elephant)
{
    ...
}

private void Handle(object fallback)
{
    // This method will be called if none of the other overloads
    // is applicable, e.g. if a "new" implementation is provided
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way without getting into advanced strategies is to use the `is` keyword.

For example:

```
Method1(IAnimal a) {
    // process NoOfFeet

    if (a is Elephant)
        DoSomething((Elephant)a);
    else if (a is Dog)
        DoSomething((Dog)a);
}
```

If `Elephant` and `Dog`, etc. might have additional subclasses that you need to specifically address, then you will need to use `typeof` instead of `is`:

```
Method1(IAnimal a) {
    // process NoOfFeet

    if (a.GetType() == typeof(Elephant))
        DoSomething((Elephant)a);
    else if (a.GetType() == typeof(Dog))
        DoSomething((Dog)a);
}
```

Comment: don't you need `typeof`

Comment: @ps2goat If the asker also wants to specifically do stuff with the different subclasses of `Elephant` and `Dog`, then yes. However, in this case `is` works just fine. I'll edit my answer though. Thanks for the input.

Comment: `typeof(a)` won't even compile, nor will `Elephant.GetType()` etc. You meant: `if (a.GetType() == typeof(Elephant))`

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh wow of course... I just wrote it in the webpage here instead of visual studio. Oops!

Answer (score 1):

Make the method a part of the class and override it.

```
public Interface IAnimal {
    int NoOfFeet;
    void DoSomething()
}

Class Animal: IAnimal {
    int NoOfFeet {get;set;}
    public virtual void DoSomething() {...}
}

Class Elephant: Animal {
    bool hasTrunk {get;set;}
    public override void DoSomething() {...}
}

Class Dog:Animal {
    string canBark {get;set;}
    public override void DoSomething() {...}
}

Method1(IAnimal a) {
    //process NoOfFeet     ...

    //process fields for derived type
    a.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to add it to the interface? This won't compile at the moment.

Comment: You need to add `DoSomething` to `IAnimal` or change the type of `a` in `Method1`.

Comment: Thanks. Thought it looked a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use the [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do stuff all animals have here

        DoSomethingVirtual(); // call virtual method to do stuff for specific animal
    }

    private abstract void DoSomethingVirtual();
}

class Elephant : Animal
{
    private override void DoSomethingVirtual()
    {
        // do elephant stuff here
    }
}
```

Now when you call `DoSomething()` on any animal object, the base class will handle the common functionality, then pass down execution to the derived class to for